# Group some values to columns by theirs names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some table with three columns:

| timestamp | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | metric_a | 0.88 |
| t1 | metric_b | 0.89 |
| t1 | metric_c | 1.00 |
| t1 | metric_d | 0.34 |
| t2 | metric_a | 0.24 |
| t2 | metric_b | 0.80 |
| t2 | metric_c | 0.00 |
| t2 | metric_d | 0.30 |

I want to build query that will return table with two columns for specified timestampe (for example, timestamp = t1):

| metrics_a_c | metrics_b_d |
| --- | --- |
| 0.88 | 0.89 |
| 1.00 | 0.34 |

I.e., I want to get two columns: 1st - metric_a and metric_c values, 2nd - metric_b and metric_d values.

---

This query is wrong:

```sql
select 
  (select value from table where key in ('metric_a', 'metric_c') ) as metrics_a_c,
  (select value from table where key in ('metric_b', 'metric_d') ) as metrics_b_d
where timestamp = t1
```

because subquery must return just one row, but here it returns two.

I found solution with union:

```sql
(select 
  (select value from table where key = 'metric_a') as metrics_a_c,
  (select value from table where key = 'metric_b') as metrics_b_d
where timestamp = t1)

union

(select 
  (select value from table where key = 'metric_c') as metrics_a_c,
  (select value from table where key = 'metric_d') as metrics_b_d
where timestamp = t1)
```

But does it possible build such query without union and two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
with t (timestamp, key, value) as (
select 't1' , 'metric_a' , 0.88  union all
select 't1' , 'metric_b' , 0.89  union all
select 't1' , 'metric_c' , 1.00  union all
select 't1' , 'metric_d' , 0.34  union all
select 't2' , 'metric_a' , 0.24  union all
select 't2' , 'metric_b' , 0.80  union all
select 't2' , 'metric_c' , 0.00  union all
select 't2' , 'metric_d' , 0.30  
)
select timestamp, case when key in ('metric_a', 'metric_b') then 'ab' else 'cd' end grp
   , max(case when key in ('metric_a', 'metric_c') then value end ) metrics_a_c
   , max(case when key in ('metric_b', 'metric_d') then value end ) metrics_b_d
from t
group by timestamp, case when key in ('metric_a', 'metric_b') then 'ab' else 'cd' end
order by timestamp, case when key in ('metric_a', 'metric_b') then 'ab' else 'cd' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the values on separate rows.  To me, that suggests using `row_number()` to separate the rows.

A general solution would do this for all timestamps:

```
select timestamp,
       max(value) filter (where (seqnum, key) in ((1, 'metric_a'), (2, 'metric_b'))) as metric_ab,
       max(value) filter (where (seqnum, key) in ((1, 'metric_c'), (2, 'metric_d'))) as metric_cd
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by timestamp, (key in ('metric_a', 'metric_b'))
                                order by key
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum, timestamp
order by timestamp, min(key);
```

You can filter in the subquery for a single timestamp.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=14a299bdd344c53304a6b99fa59da43b) is a db<>fiddle.